# Error while compiling with nodejs

Tags: solidity, javascript, compilation

Im trying to set up the compiler for my project.

sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract Inbox {
    string public message;
    
    function Inbox(string initialMessage) public{
        message = initialMessage;
    }
    
    function setMessage(string newMessage) public{
        message = newMessage;
    }
     
}
```

js:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs  = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'UTF-8');

console.log(solc.compile(source));
```

but for some reason I get the following error while trying to compile it on the cmd:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:944
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\marko\solidityproject\compile.js'
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:941:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:774:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

I've already tried reinstalling the solc multiple times. Could anyone give me a hand?

Comment: What solc version are you using? Since solc v0.5 the compile function expect a JSON input with the source description. In order to compile for v0.4 you have to explicitly install solc from v0.4 branch, I think this is the most recent version from that branch https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc/v/0.4.26.

Comment: I managed to fix it, honestly Im not sure what the issue was exactly, I litreally deleted the JS file and rewrote from scratch and it worked!

Comment: It's good you have fixed it, perhaps it was a case of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging. I happened to all of us.